# I am getting an error while implementing the operator* and operator-> operators. Can someone help me what is the issue?

Tags: visual-c++

So I am making an iterator class and I'm getting an error that "Cannot convert from NT * const to VT &" in operator* and operator->. I have tried return *itr and return it but had no luck.

```
template<typename NT, typename VT>
class node_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, NT, VT, NT&>
{
private:
    NT* itr;

public:
    node_iterator(NT* nd = nullptr) : itr(nd) {}

    node_iterator& operator++ () // Pre-increment
    {
        +itr;
        return (*this);
    }

    node_iterator operator++ (int) // Post-increment
    {
        auto temp(*this);
        ++itr;
        return temp;
    }

    // two-way comparison: v.begin() == v.cbegin() and vice versa
    template<class TT>
    bool operator == (const node_iterator<TT, VT>& rhs)
    {
        if (this->itr == rhs.itr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<class TT>
    bool operator != (const node_iterator<TT, VT>& rhs)
    {
        if (this->itr != rhs.itr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    VT& operator* () const
    {
        return itr;
    }

    VT& operator-> () const
    {
        return *itr;
    }

    operator node_iterator<NT, const VT>() const
    {
        return node_iterator<NT, const VT>(itr);
    }
};
```

Can someone kindly guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the relationship between `NT` and `VT`? How is this class expected to be used? Show a [mcve].

Comment: NT is the value_type and VT is the pointer I guess.

Comment: What do you mean, you guess? What parameters is this class actually instantiated with, in your program? Once again, for further assistance prepare a [mcve].